# Save whole page source using php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save full webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722433/save-full-webpage)

I need to save page source of external link using PHP , Like we saving in PC.

p.s :saved folder has images and html contents.

I tried below code...it just puts the source in tes.html , i need to save all images too.So we access if offline.

```
<?php
include 'curl.php';
$game = load("https://otherdomain.com/");
echo $game;
?>

<?php 
file_put_contents('tes.html', $game);
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? just parse the HTML, and get all `href` attributes you need. Alter the `href` attribute so that the images will be loaded off-line and _Robert's your uncle_

Comment: This is not a trivial task and can't be easily done using curl. Image locations have to be parsed from the HTML source, images fetched and the URL rewritten. The same must be done for CSS files, JavaScript files, background images...

There are command line tools that are better at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is mirroring a web site.

I would use the program `wget` to do so instead of reinventing the wheel.

```
exec( 'wget -mk -w 20 http://www.example.com/' );
```

See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget
- http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/create-a-mirror-of-a-website-with-wget/

Comment: It's the correct term! I took the liberty of removing your question.

Comment: Does `wget` fetch style sheets and images without `--page-requisites` though? I thought `-m` just follows hrefs

Comment: where does this save all contents ?

Comment: @Vidya Venkat `wget` creates a subdirectory with the domain as name inside the current working directory.

Comment: Its not saving any thing in current folder...wget is installed though

Comment: It just saved index.html..not images

Answer (score 0):

Either write your own solution to parse all the CSS, image and JS links (and save them) or check this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1722513/143732

Comment: Good catch! Indeed, this is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a scraper and, by the looks of it, you're not yet skilled for such an endeavor. Consider studying:

1. **Web Scraping** (cURL, StreamContext in PHP, HTTP theory)
2. **URL** paths (relative, absolute, resolving)
3. **DOMDocument** and **DOMXPath** (for parsing HTML and easy tag querying)
4. Overall **HTML** structure (IMG, LINK, SCRIPT and other tags that load external content)
5. Overall **CSS** structure (like url('...') in CSS that loads resources the page depends on)

*And only then will you be able to mirror a site, properly.* But if they load content dynamically, like with Ajax, you're out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

[file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) also supports http(s). Example:

```
$game = file_get_contents('https://otherdomain.com');
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP wants

Comment: Sorry, should have read the complete question...